# Add Second index of array in to another array's second index

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I am newbie in iOS development, i know this question is easy but i try many times but i not got any solution here i want to add array's second index value in to another array's second index for that i write a code like as

```
for (int i=0; i<[category.subCategoriesArray count]; i++)
{
    SubCategory *subCategory = [category.subCategoriesArray objectAtIndex:i];
    [self.categoryArray addObject:subCategory.name];
    for(int j = 0; j<[subCategory.itemsArray count]; j++)
    {
        Item *item = [subCategory.itemsArray objectAtIndex:j];
        [self.subCategoryArray addObject:item.name];
        [self.itemContents addObject:item.itemContents];
    }
    NSInteger count=[subCategory.itemsArray count];
    [self.countArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:count]];
    NSOrderedSet *orderedSet = [NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithArray:self.categoryArray];
    self.mainCategory = orderedSet.array;
}
```

Here i want to add my `subcategory.itemsArray` first index in to `self.subCategoryArray` first index and for second index in to my arrays second index but here i got `self.subCategoryArray` is the mixing of all my `subcategory.itemsArray` . here in first index `subcategory.itemsArray` has 13 object and for second index it have only 1 object then i want `self.subCategoryArray` array have first index contain 13 object and second contain 1 object but i got `self.subCategoryArray` all object in to array in first index.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly but maybe the following methods on `NSMutableArray` might help.

```
[array insertObject:object atIndex:index];
[array insertObjects:anotherArray atIndexes:someNSIndexSet];
```